# How to sort list start with first and then contains string search in md-autocomplete AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, md-autocomplete

I'm new to angularJs and want to filter the search result.

Here is the example :
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mpJyKm

I want search result based on query input filtered such as string starts with come first in the result list and then contains. I'm using **md-autocomplete** example and want to filter list in **controller** only.

```
e.g. If search input is : A
then result should be like this :
Alabama
Alaska
Arizona
Arkansas
California
Colorado
...
```

tried this for filtering result but returning Starts with or contains in any order without filtering as I need:

```
function createFilterFor(query) {
    var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
    return function filterFn(state) {
    return (state.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) != -1);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `querySearch()` function like this:

```
function querySearch (query) {
  var q = angular.lowercase(query);
  var results = self.states
    .reduce(function(res, state) {
      var idx = state.value.indexOf(q);
      if(idx === 0) {
        res[0].push(state)
      } else if(idx > 0) {
        res[1].push(state)
      }
      return res;   
    },[[],[]])
  return results[0].concat(results[1]);
}
```

You can go through all states and put those that match query into one of two arrays: the first one is where the state starts from query, and the second if the match is in the middle. After forming these arrays, you can concat them. Since your `allStates` are already sorted alphabetically, you don't need to apply extra sorting afterwards.

Also, if you want to highlight the matching pattern in case-insensitive way, you should add `md-highlight-flags="i"` to your item template

```
<md-item-template>
    <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText" 
          md-highlight-flags="i">{{item.display}}</span>
</md-item-template>
```

**CodePen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QajOqj/

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
md-items="item in querySearch(searchText) | orderBy : 'fieldName'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Vadim's is an excellent solution. Here's a generic TS version:

```
interface QuerySearchProps {
  query: string;
  data: any;
  propToMatch: string;
}

export const querySearch = ({query, data, propToMatch}: QuerySearchProps) => {
  const q = query.toLowerCase();
  const results = data.reduce(
    function (res: any, item: any) {
      const idx = item[propToMatch].toLowerCase().indexOf(q);
      if (idx === 0) {
        res[0].push(item);
      } else if (idx > 0) {
        res[1].push(item);
      }
      return res;
    },
    [[], []],
  );
  return results[0].concat(results[1]);
};
```